# Please explain the default constructor (int = 10)

Tags: arrays, class, constructor, operators, overloading

```
class Array
{
public:

Array(int = 10); // default constructor
~Array(); // destructor

protected:

int size; // number of elements in the Array
int *ptr; // address of dynamically allocated memory
};
```

Could someone explain what the default constructor (int = 10) is about,  with an example? Also, how do I create a new object with type Array and automatically assign values to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would answer your first question and would like you to inquire more on how would you approach to the second problem. Until and unless you work through the compilation issues, you won't get that vision that you need to approach any other computer problem.

In the below code,

```
`Array(int size = 10)` has been written. It means that during construction of the object of class Array, it needs a parameter of `int` type but even if you fail to give the parameter, it would construct the object with `size=10`. This overwrites the "Zero Initialization" behavior to "Default Initialization".
```

Also,

```
`Array(int=10), Array(int='a')`, these are similar as `Array()`
```

Please find the code below and let me know if you have any issues. Again I would like you to inquire more on the second part by yourself. Generalize you answer and try asking it through on google.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Array
{
public:

Array(int='a')// default constructor
{
    this->size = size;
} 
~Array() // destructor
{

}
int getSize()
{
 return size;
}
protected:

int size; // number of elements in the Array
int *ptr; // address of dynamically allocated memory
};

int main()
{
    Array one;
    cout<<one.getSize();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have another question though. How do I merge values of one Array onto another using the += operator?

Comment: You will have to overload the += operator. Draft a question and put that up Or rather try and search on how to overload an operator. You will find stuff.

I am glad I could help.